# terminal lauch but doesn't finish loading

Tags: gnome, 22.04, gnome-terminal

I am unsure if I am wording this correctly, but when I try to open the terminal, it opens, but It never finishes loading (So I can't type anything in there)it stays in the below state.
[image]

Comment: Did you recently install, remove, update anything, set an alias, etc? If so, please edit to include links to the directions used, or paste the exact commands in back ticks (\`like this\`). [Possibly relevant Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640083/gnome-terminal-not-starting-due-to-error-in-python-script-related-to-gi) - not sure, so try to diagnose it based on what they're saying rather than just run the commands. Running `gnome-terminal` in another terminal seems like a good starting point.

Comment: The _terminal_ loads perfectly. It launches the program you ask it to launch, presumably your default shell. It's _that app_ that doesn't start up properly.

Comment: (1) you've set the terminal's custom command to something that isn't a shell (2) you've added a long-running (or possibly non-terminating) command to one of the shell's startup files (~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.profile, ~/.zshrc etc.) (3) you have made the shell's startup sequence recursive - for example by sourcing ~/.profile from ~/.bashrc and also sourcing ~/.bashrc from ~/.profile

Comment: Thanks guys, you were right, I installed ng and it was stuck in a ng latin completion so I commented it out on .bashrc and it started to work again. Thanks again for your help